# Dynamic substitution of column headers in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, list

I have a dataframe like this:

```
example_df =

country  id  metric_name  metric_value account_id
US       1   clicks       111          000
UK       2   clicks       222          000
DE       3   clicks       333          000
RU       4   clicks       444          000
```

And a variable with dimensions

```
breakdowns = 'country'
```

I need to substitute a columns header of 'country' column in example_df with 'metric_key_1'

It could be different dimensions names in breakdowns variable, not only country. And the max length could be 2, so breakdowns = 'age,gender' for example. And if breakdowns = '0', nothing should happen.

So my target result looks like this if breakdowns = 'country'

```
metric_key_1   id  metric_name  metric_value account_id
US             1   clicks       111          000
UK             2   clicks       222          000
DE             3   clicks       333          000
RU             4   clicks       444          000
```

And if breakdowns = 'age,gender'

```
metric_key_1  metric_key_2    id  metric_name  metric_value account_id
18-24         female          1   clicks       111          000
25-44         male            2   clicks       222          000
45-65         male            3   clicks       333          000
65-100        female          4   clicks       444          000
```

What I have done so far

```
#  got the columns headers in a list
columns_list = list(example_df)
#  check if berakdown is empty
if breakdowns == '0':
    pass
else:
    #  split them to a list
    breakdowns = breakdowns.split(',')
    #  substitute names with metric_key_n
    breakdowns1 = ['metric_key_{}'.format(i) for i in range(1, len(breakdowns) + 1)]
    #  here I get an error
    for x in breakdowns1:
        if x not in columns_list:
            for x,y in zip(breakdowns1, columns_list):
                columns_list[x] = y

Error:

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-78-a3a989b94f92> in <module>
      2         if x not in columns_list:
      3             for x,y in zip(breakdowns1, columns_list):
----> 4                 columns_list[x] = y

TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

I know the solution is not hard, but just can't get it. Appreciate any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest create dictionary with dict comprehension with `split` and `enumerate` and then `rename` columns by it:

```
breakdowns = 'country'
d = {c: 'metric_key_{}'.format(i) for i, c in enumerate(breakdowns.split(','), 1)}
print (d)
{'country': 'metric_key_1'}

df = df.rename(columns=d)
print (df)

  metric_key_1  id metric_name  metric_value  account_id
0           US   1      clicks           111           0
1           UK   2      clicks           222           0
2           DE   3      clicks           333           0
3           RU   4      clicks           444           0
```